# Convert array into object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, react-native, object

Hello friends I have one JSON as below

```
 "specifications": [
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_promotionIds",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "PromotionIds",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_productType",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "ProductType",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_itemStatus",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "Item Status",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "number",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "minValue": -9.99999999999E11,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_promotionAmount",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "maxValue": 9.99999999999E11,
        "length": 12,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "PromotionAmount",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "number",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_inventoryLocation",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "Inventory Location",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "number",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "minValue": -9.99999999999E11,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_couponAmount",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "maxValue": 9.99999999999E11,
        "length": 12,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "CouponAmount",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "number",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_couponCodes",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "CouponCodes",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_couponPromotionIds",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "CouponPromotionIds",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "checkbox",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_isINSTALLATIONREQUIRED",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 19,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "IsInstallationRequired",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "checkbox",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    }
]
```

i need to construct object like below

```
{
  "c_promotionIds" : null,
  "c_productType" : null,
  "c_itemStatus" :null,
  "c_promotionAmount" : null, 
  "c_inventoryLocation" : null, 
  "c_couponAmount" : null,
  "c_couponCodes" : null,
  "c_couponPromotionIds" : null,
  "c_isINSTALLATIONREQUIRED" :null
}
```

I tried like below but not working

```
let comObject = {}, 
for (let index = 0; index < responseData.specifications.length; index++) {
                
                comObject = {
                    responseData.specifications[index].id : null,
                }
            }
```

any idea how i can construct this?

Comment: i have idea. you can check it.

let comObject = {};
for (let index = 0; index < responseData.specifications.length; index++) {
    comObject [responseData.specifications[index].id] = null;
}
console.log(comObject);

Comment: @MaiTruong Yes it is working thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the object on each iteration of the array, you need to add new keys to the object and keep the ones you have already assigned.

Also, to indicate that `id` is the key, you need to sorround it with brackets []

```
let comObject = {};
for (let index = 0; index < responseData.specifications.length; index++) {
comObject = {
    ...comObject,
    [responseData.specifications[index].id] : null,
            }
 }
```

There's a method in the array prototype called [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that is designed for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const  specifications = [
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_promotionIds",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "PromotionIds",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_productType",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "ProductType",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_itemStatus",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "Item Status",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "number",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "minValue": -9.99999999999E11,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_promotionAmount",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "maxValue": 9.99999999999E11,
        "length": 12,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "PromotionAmount",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "number",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_inventoryLocation",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "Inventory Location",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "number",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "minValue": -9.99999999999E11,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_couponAmount",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "maxValue": 9.99999999999E11,
        "length": 12,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "CouponAmount",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "number",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_couponCodes",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "CouponCodes",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "shortText",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_couponPromotionIds",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 254,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "CouponPromotionIds",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "shortText",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    },
    {
        "validationPattern": null,
        "itemType": "commerceItem",
        "readAccessRight": null,
        "securityMaskingValue": null,
        "type": "checkbox",
        "writeSecurityLevel": null,
        "required": false,
        "writable": true,
        "default": null,
        "audienceVisibility": null,
        "textSearchable": false,
        "writeRole": null,
        "id": "c_isINSTALLATIONREQUIRED",
        "dimension": false,
        "shopperWriteable": false,
        "readRole": null,
        "readSecurityLevel": null,
        "length": 19,
        "shopperReadable": false,
        "label": "IsInstallationRequired",
        "writeAccessRight": null,
        "searchable": false,
        "uiEditorType": "checkbox",
        "localizable": false,
        "multiSelect": null
    }
];

const result = {};
specifications.forEach(spec => result[spec.id] = null);

console.log(result);
```